# Worklight iOS native build fails on Jenkins

Tags: ios, ant, jenkins, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to do a Jenkins build for a Worklight hybrid application. I am able to build the hybrid part of the application, but when I try to create the .ipa file the build fails. I am using the example ANT script from the Worklight documentation. The build is actually succeeding, but the ipa is not being created. When the script executes the xcrun command

```
 <exec
        dir="${wlappdir}/${mobilePlatform}/native"
        executable="${iosPackageCMD}"
        failonerror="false"
        output="${iosPackageCMDlog}"
        resultproperty="iosPackageCMDResult" >

        <arg value="-sdk" />

        <arg value="iphoneos" />

        <arg value="PackageApplication" />

        <arg value="${wlappdir}/${mobilePlatform}/native/build/Release-iphoneos/${wlApp}.app" />

        <arg value="-o" />

        <arg value="${local.ipaPath}/${wlApp}-${version}.ipa" />

        <arg value="--sign" />

        <arg value="${certificate}" />

        <arg value="--embed" />

        <arg value="${provisioning.profile}" />

        <arg value="-verbose" />
    </exec>
```

I get the following error in the logs:

```
error: Specified application doesn't exist or isn't a bundle directory : '[my path]/JQMShowcase.app'
```

When I look in the workspace, that file is definitely there. I am also pretty sure that all of the variables are correct for the script.

Comment: Are running xcrun? looks like it, your script looks correct, i would really double check that directory. maybe do an echo of ${wlappdir}/${mobilePlatform}/native/build/Release-iphoneos/${wlApp}.app to make sure. is wlappdir relative?

Comment: Hi, wlappdir is relative. I tried to echo that file as you suggested and it was there. I tried using an absolute path, but this is not working either.

Answer (score 2):

We are currently using Jenkins 1.518 with the XCode Integration Plugin 1.3.3. from https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin.

We are configuring and using it through the web-interface Jenkins provides, so I am unfortunately not really familiar with your exact problem.

---

For the Worklight build we execute the worklight ANT tasks according to:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_for_building_and_dep.html?resultof=%22%61%6e%74%22%20

---

For the iOS build we have a second jenkins server that is kicked-off by the first one, once worklight build is complete and the iOS native folder is copied to the right place using FTP:

We had to configure the Xcode Builder configuration in the Jenkins global config:

```
xcodebuild executable path  /usr/bin/xcodebuild
agvtool executable path /usr/bin/agvtool
xcrun executable path   /usr/bin/xcrun
```

In the specific build job for the iOS project we have 2 build steps: Execute Shell and XCode:

Execute Shell build step: some commands before the xcode plugin build (MASTER_BUILD_NUMBER is a simple String parameter that we set/pass to parameterize our builds):

```
echo $MASTER_BUILD_NUMBER
rm -rf Build_*
cp -rf /Users/Shared/Jenkins/UPLOAD/$MASTER_BUILD_NUMBER .
cd $MASTER_BUILD_NUMBER/native
chmod u+x buildtime.sh
```

XCode build step: for the xcode plugin part of the build we configured:

- Xcode Project Directory: ${MASTER_BUILD_NUMBER}/native
- check the "Build IPA" checkbox
- Build output directory: ${HOME}/Home/jobs/XCODE_buildTest1/workspace/${MASTER_BUILD_NUMBER}/native/build/Release-iphoneos
- Code Signing Identity: iPhone Distribution: XXX Ltd.
- Embedded Profile: ${HOME}/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX.mobileprovision

(.. the XXX's are our company specific data)